# Huge differences in size from Camtasia file to mp4 format

Tags: camtasia

I am using Camtasia to record a video from the screen. I have seen that a video of 5 minutes generates a camrec file of approximately 5.6 Gb, but when I convert it to mp4 it gets reduced to approximately 800 Mb. I see that the mp4 generated is of good quality, but why there is a huge difference in size within both formats? I am converting to the mp4 by using the recorded session screen size seetings.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Well there is a huge difference if you want to record video or if you want to convert a video. In the first case everything has to work i real-time, otherwise you loos data. In the latter you have time, enough time to use efficient but slow encoding with settings for high quality. So In my opinion this is a trade off: when Camtasia was developed the developer thought that it is more likely to have a PC with fast HDD than one with a high-quality real-time video encoder.

Comment: @Robert - that could be an answer.

Comment: @Robert, so that is the reason why the generated mp4 format has the same quality? I have never thought of that comparison that you made of the fast HDD and the video encoder